# How to fix 'xyz.push(a) is not a function' error in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, postman

I am new in the RESTful API world. So, I am learning to work with it without using any database. As exercise, I want to build 2 endpoints

- POST auth/signup
- POST auth/signin

When I try to test my signup endpoint with Postman I am getting some errors and unexpected behaviour.

The structure of my files is like this:

**data/users**:

```
let users = [ 
    {
       id: 1,
       email: 'user@gmail.com',
       name: 'You',
       password: 'Pat123'
    }
];

module.export = users;
```

**routes/signUp.routes.js**:

```js
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

const usr = require('../data/users');
//import usr from '../data/users'; // not yet supported (natively)

//const m = require('../helpers/middlewares');

/* Create a new user */
router.post('/', (req, res) => {

if(!req.body.email) {
    return res.status(404).send({
    status: 404,
    message: 'email is required',
    });
} else if(!req.body.name) {
    return res.status(404).send({
    status: 404,
    message: 'name is required'
    });
  }
const userNew = {
    id: usr.length + 1,
    email: req.body.email,
    name: req.body.name,
    password: 'user123',
};
usr.push(userNew);
return res.status(200).send({
    status: 200,
    message: 'New user added successfully',
    userNew,
    });
});

// Routes
module.exports = router;
```

I also have config file on the root to run the server on port 3000.

If I run the code above on Postman I only get the result from the first if statement even though everything is OK to pass that test. I don't figure out why.

If I comment that bloc (if and if else) I get an error message saying that usr.push() is not a function.

I spent some hours trying to resolve but in vain. Is there something wrong with my code?

**Edit**: I changed my file structure, I don't get `usr.push()` is not function error any more. But the bloc if else if doesn't still work well. The request responds only with the first bloc even though I send all required field or I send one of them.

Comment: `module.exports`, not `module.export`

Answer (score 0):

By default, `req.body` is `undefined` and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as body-parser and multer. [Reference](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req)

Install `body-parser` by running the command `npm install --save body-parser`

Then, in your code

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Now, you should be able to access the request body.
Do not forget to set a request header `content-type` as `application/json`

Comment: I am using 
```app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```
I tried to install body-parser but it can't still resolve the issue. I don't think that is the problem, because I do access the ```req.body```. If I comment the if else if bloc I easily access the data.